# Dovecot not listening on any port

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am trying to setup a mail server, but Dovecot is not listening on any port. I  have tried troubleshooting but unfortunately have hit a brickwall. Any help / suggestions would be much appreciated thanks.

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#smtpd_use_tls=yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
#smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 permit_mynetworks,
 reject_unauth_destination
```

**dovecot -n**

```
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian 8.8 ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap lmtp
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
 service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = no
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

**service dovecot status**

```
● dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-06-23 21:33:08 CEST; 13min ago
 Main PID: 7688 (dovecot)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dovecot.service
           ├─7688 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F
           ├─7690 dovecot/anvil
           ├─7691 dovecot/log
           └─7693 dovecot/config

Jun 23 21:33:08 spmac1 systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
Jun 23 21:33:08 spmac1 systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Jun 23 21:33:08 spmac1 dovecot[7688]: master: Dovecot v2.2.13 starting up for imap, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
```

**netstat -tupln**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7557/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55171           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      463/rpc.statd   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:xxxx            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1274/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      964/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7557/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      454/rpcbind     
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      7557/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::52219                :::*                    LISTEN      463/rpc.statd   
tcp6       0      0 :::50122                :::*                    LISTEN      1274/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      7557/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      454/rpcbind     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      643/apache2     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:629             0.0.0.0:*                           454/rpcbind     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:639           0.0.0.0:*                           463/rpc.statd   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52688           0.0.0.0:*                           463/rpc.statd   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8217            0.0.0.0:*                           391/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           391/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           454/rpcbind     
udp6       0      0 :::629                  :::*                                454/rpcbind     
udp6       0      0 :::25374                :::*                                391/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::34693                :::*                                463/rpc.statd   
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                454/rpcbind
```

**tail /var/log/mail.log**

```
Jun 23 21:20:03 spmac1 dovecot: lmtp(3589): Connect from local
Jun 23 21:20:03 spmac1 dovecot: lmtp(3589): Disconnect from local: Successful quit
Jun 23 21:20:03 spmac1 postfix/qmgr[1264]: 8518441BFC: removed
Jun 23 21:32:43 spmac1 postfix/master[1259]: terminating on signal 15
Jun 23 21:32:43 spmac1 postfix/master[7557]: daemon started -- version 2.11.3, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 23 21:33:08 spmac1 dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 23 21:33:08 spmac1 dovecot: anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 23 21:33:08 spmac1 dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 23 21:33:08 spmac1 dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.13 starting up for imap, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
```

As you can see in the output of netstat, Dovecot is nowhere to be found; neither port 993 or 143 are open. I have also tried telneting to these ports aswell and can confirm they are in fact closed.

Comment: Are you following a how-to or just kinda hoping it works out of the box?  I recommend this guide - https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie - I've tested a working setup being upgraded to stretch and it all still worked, but i don't know if inital creation would work under stretch.

Comment: [tag:postfix] is a red herring here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others who may have similar issues, the closed ports issue in this particular configuration was caused by :

```
 service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
```

The port number must be either specified (143 for IMAP). Alternatively, the "port = 0" line should be commented out which will allow dovecot to fallback and use default port values.

Another issue with this configuration is that, ssl was set to "no" where it should have been set to "required" seeing as snake-oil certificates are used in postfix config. As such, these should also be used in the dovecot config.

```
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem 
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```